# Access 2010 DLookUp

Tags: ms-access, filtering

Working with MS Access for the first time and coming across a few problems if someone could please point me in the right direction.

So I'm doing a mock database (so it looks silly) just to learn the ins and outs and need some help with DLookUp at the moment.

My database has two tables, with the following fields:
`C_ID` the PK in Courses and FK in Student

```
tblCourse: C_ID, Title, Subject                              
tblStudent: S_ID, C_ID, Name, EnrollDATE
```

As I said this is just for testing/learning. So what I want is to have a filter that gives me a list of `C_ID`'s based on which `EnrollDates` are `NULL`.

so filter is:

```
Expr1: DLookUp("[tblStudent]![C_ID]","tblStudent","isNull([tblStudent]![EnrollDATE])")
```

I have also tried with the criteria being

```
 [tblStudent]![EnrollDATE] = Null
```

Currently I get just blank fields returned. Any help is greatly appreciated, and please ask me to elaborate if my explanation is off.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
DLookup("C_ID", "tblStudent", "EnrollDate is null")
```

1. You don't need to include the table name when you specify the columns
2. In Access, you check for `Null` by using `xxx is null` or `xxx is not null`

Note that `DLookup` only returns **one** value (if the criteria matches more than one row, the value is taken from any row), so you can't use it to get a list of `C_ID`s back.

---

**EDIT:**
What you actually want to do is select data from one table, and filter that based on data from  the other table, correct?
Like, selecting all courses where at least one student has an empty `EnrollDATE`?

If yes, you don't need the `DLookup` at all, there are two different ways how to do that:

1) With a sub-select:

```
select *
from tblCourse
where C_ID in
(
    select C_ID
    from tblStudents
    where EnrollDATE is null
)
```

2) By joining the tables:

```
select tblCourse.*
from tblCourse
inner join tblStudent on tblCourse.C_ID = tblStudent.C_ID
where tblStudent.EnrollDATE is null
```

This is SQL, so you need to [switch to SQL View](http://www.jaffainc.com/SQLStatementsInAccess.htm#Access2007) in your query in Access.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, but since I am looking for a list what would be my next option.

Comment: I just read that you figured it out, but I already finished editing my answer. See above!

Comment: Your solution 1 was much better then what I tried, I tip my cap once again sir.