# How do I update a field on a form based on another entered field in Access 2013?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

So far I've had no luck finding an answer to this, so here we go:

I would like to create a form for the input of product returns as follows:

Each product has a "GPC" field and a "ProductName" field.
e.g. GPC= 123ABC & ProductName= Greenstar (apples, 1kg)

My idea is to have these 2 fields as 2 separate combo boxes on my form, allowing the user to enter the product using either the GPC or the ProductName field.

In order for this to work, I would need the respective fields to update immediately after data input to return the matching other field;
i.e. user enters GPC= 123ABC and ProductName immediately displays "Greenstar (apples, 1kg)" and vice versa.

Is there a way to do this in Access 2013?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Guessing you have the product's in one table with GPC and ProductName fields.   Each combo box uses the same table as it's row source but bound by either field 1 or 2.   So, for example, after the update of combobox A, set the value of combo box B by using a DLOOKUP (on the product table) based on the value of combo box A.

Comment: can we see and example of the data in the table? im assuming that both of the fields are in the same table

Comment: This is simply cascading combo boxes. BinGoogle it. There are probably thousands of posts on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Dlookup function. Just put it into your control source for the field you want populated.

[Access 2010 DLookUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196724/access-2010-dlookup)